# Not getting change in validation accuracy

Tags: neural-network, lstm, sentiment-analysis

I am using nn for sentiment analysis and im getting good results but my validation accuracy and loss are not changing much even though training accuracy increases or decrease

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While I know the pains of working with machine learning, your question doesn't really describe what you want to know. If you want peope to be able to help, you need a clear description of your problem and preferably a minimum example as well.

Comment: This is almost the textbook definition of over-fitting. I'd suggest you delete this question, read up on over-fitting (generally, and then specific to LSTM), then come back if you have a more specific question. BTW the cross-validated site has 7 questions tagged with both overfitting and lstm: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/overfitting+lstm